# accessing the json file in jquery template

Tags: json, jquery

I want the json to be in the json file and want to access in the jquery template how can i do that your help be  appreciated

```
var movies = [
  { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
  { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
  { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
  ];

var markup = "<li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>";

/* Compile the markup as a named template */
$.template( "movieTemplate", markup );

/* Render the template with the movies data and insert
   the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element */
$.tmpl( "movieTemplate", movies )
  .appendTo( "#movieList" );
```

now i am trying to access the name filed only how can i access the name field from json file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('dat.js', function(data) {
             $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( data[i].name).appendTo( "#movieList" );
            });
```

});

want to access the field but  error showing as data[0] is undifined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to load the json file content:

```
var markup = "<li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>";

/* Compile the markup as a named template */
$.template( "movieTemplate", markup );

$.getJSON('movies.json', function(data) {

  // 'data' is the json loaded and parsed from the file
  $.tmpl( "movieTemplate", data )
     .appendTo( "#movieList" );

});
```

Comment: i want to access the name field from the json file ... can you help me out

Comment: `data[0].Name` will give you the value of the property Name of the first element in the array.